# Groovy POI created cells considered blank by other programs until ENTER is manually pressed in cells

Tags: excel, groovy

Ok this is kind of hard to explain.

I create a cell in my worksheet using JAVA POI

```
  newCell= row.getCell(index)
  if (containerCell == null) {
          containerCell = row.createCell(index)
  }
  newCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
  newCell.setCellValue(strVar)
```

If i then open the worksheet in EXCEL, I see that the cell value is indeed set. However if I load this into another external program that reads EXCEL sheets, it claims the cell I just set is blank.

NOW, if I go back into excel and do a simple "Hit return" on the cell in question, in the formula bar (even though its not a formula) and try to reload it into the external program, it works fine. Do I need to evaluate a formula on a string?

Thanks

Comment: What's your actual code?  I assume that's not the real code above, as you have `newCell` and then `containerCell`? Also, what version of POI are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this was happening.. and evaluating the individual cells did not solve it however running `evaluteAll()` on the entire workbook made it work!

Comment: cool! I didn't even realize `evaluteAll()` existed ... good work!

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Java, but having to hit enter in a cell is usually indicative of calculation being set to manual.  Since you are working with API it may be treating your input from Java as a formula (?).

Open the offending workbook in its broken state, and on the sheet you are having problems with choose [Formulas] tab at top, then [Calculation]>Calculate Sheet.

If this updates the value then I see two options...

See if there is an option to manually calculate the sheet with POI, after the value has been entered.

Alternatively, you can write just a *tiny* bit of VBA to force calculation on that sheet when workbook is opened.  MSDN offers a simple example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223802%28v=office.11%29.aspx

I have had to do this for Excel apps where calculation had to be set to manual to avoid excessive overhead.  Just a guess though..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but calculate sheet does not update the value, and its already set to automatic. If i try pressing Evaluate Formula it says its a constant. Its only the Enter key

Comment: Ok this is another shot in the dark, but what if you copy/paste values in the source workbook, *then* open the new workbook.  Also, are you in 64 or 32 bit environment?  I have seen where some API's struggle with 64 bit excel.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant about source/new workbook. If I copy and paste the same values in the same cells it works. I'm on 32 bit

Comment: I also notice when I first open the generated excel (from POI) those cells in question are selected or highlighted...odd

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the number of workbooks.  So if you copy/paste the values your other program can read the cells?

Comment: yes. copy/paste or pressing ENTER in the formula bar both work

Comment: Ok so I found this at an Excel forum http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=139250  If you read towards the end, it mentions that you can have unexpected results when using the selection object in a function.  I have had bizarre results as well.  You did mention that the range is selected once you first open the workbook.  I wonder if POI uses the selection object to 'Get' cells.  Is there an alternative method in the API?  Also, it may be worthwhile to insert the value as a formula as you mentioned.  If none of that works, it is easy to open the workbook & copy/paste the range with VBA.